# The mongoose find() method is not a function error in the service call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

When I tried to implement an express get service call with a mongoose find method it is giving me  '*Product.find*' is not a function error.

FYI-'Product' is the mongoose model which I imported .

### ROUTES FILE

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();
const Product = require('../models/product');

routes.get('/',(req,res)=>{
const list= Product.find();
res.send(list);
})
```

### MODEL FILE

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:String,
subject:String
})
exports.Product = mongoose.model('Product',productSchema);
```

### ERROR

```
TypeError:Product.find is not a function.
```

Comment: Try `module.export = mongoose.model("Product",productSchema);`

Answer (score 2):

When you are exporting the model like `exports.Product`,you need to import the model in routes file as an object.

```
const {Product} = require('../models/product');
```

OR

we can use `module.exports` instead of `exports.Product` without making any changes in the import of routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not importing your model in route file. Better if you can use `module.exports` instead of exports.Product.